# Aliasing - Nyquist frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

According to [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NyquistFrequency.html)

"
in order to recover all Fourier components of a periodic waveform, it is necessary to use a sampling rate $\nu$ at least twice \textit{highest} waveform frequency. The Nyquist frequency, also called the Nyquist limit is the highest frequency that can be coded ata a given sampling rate in order to tbe able to fully reconstruct the signal, i.e.,

$$
f_{\text{Nyquist}} = \frac{1}{2}v
$$
"

Here what I don't understand: how can this equality be true when you have a frequency (e.g. with unit Hz) on one side and a velocity (e.g. with using m/s) on the other side of the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sampling rate ν is also in Hz. It is the number of observations per second - the rate at which you are sampling data.

Both sides of the equation are in the same units. Hertz.

And that’s a Greek letter ν (nu), not an English letter v.